# Update JSFiddle result on separate window

Tags: jsfiddle

I have a JSFiddle which requires a larger screen than the result window. Ideally, I'd like to "detach the result" window onto a separate monitor.

I have used the fullscreen result page, however I can only refresh it if I update the fiddle and then change the number in the URL.

Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

The older answer wouldn't work. What I found that works is appending `show/` to the url, like

```
http://jsfiddle.net/wptc/cgGXe/show/
```

It should give you just the result tab.

Comment: Thanks, does this update when saving the fiddle?

Comment: As long as the url points to a valid saved fiddle, adding show should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Debug on Mobile button, the first button to the right of RUN. You may need an account and sign in to jsFiddle to use this feature. This URL should reflect the current base for this fork in show mode.

Or, you can try the right click on run button. This should show the run-state in a new tab or window.

Adding #Run to the base URL may do the trick.  http://jsfiddle.net/wptc/cgGXe/#run

Ah, how about Collaboration with yourself?

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks @cSco they are great ideas, +1, but unfortunately the mobile debugger said not connected. And although the right click > run looked promising. I'm hoping for a way that when I make changes to a fiddle (not necessarily update it), that the detached screen will refresh also.